# Getting an error while upgrading my application in android market

Tags: android

Whenever I try to upgrade my application in `Android Market`, I am getting this error:

```
The `apk` file must be signed with at least one certificate in common with the previous version.
```

and I have lost my previous `keystore`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work really *really* **really** ***really*** hard to find your previous keystore. Otherwise, you are out of luck. As the error indicates, you have to sign updates with the same key as before, and if you no longer have that key, you are stuck.